# Comparator java - порядок в зависимости от иерархии

Tags: java, сортировка

Есть суперкласс:

```
public class Car {
private String name; 
...    
}
```

И дочерний класс:

```
public class PassengerCar extends Car {
...
}
```

Необходимо отсортировать коллекцию `List<Car>` по имени. Как сделать так, чтобы в случае совпадения имен сначала был объект суперкласса, а затем подкласса?

```
public class SortedByName implements Comparator<Car>{
@Override
public int compare(Car o1, Car o2) {
    String name1 = o1.getName();
    String name2 = o2.getName();
    if (name1.compareTo(name2) == 0){
      return ???;
   }
}
```

Пример:

```
List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();
cars.add(new PassengerCar("bmw"));
cars.add(new Car("bmw"));
Comparator<Car> comparator = new SortedByName();
Collections.sort(cars, comparator);
```

Comment: думаю тут Вам поможет рефлексия

Comment: или в `Comparator`'е добавить проверку на instanceof

Comment: @Tsyklop  Ааа, не мог додуматься как используя рефлексию либо intanceOf отсортировать. Нужно было всего то вернуть -1, 0 либо 1 в зависимости от результата. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовать рефлексию и метод getClass() либо instanceOf. В зависимости от необходимого результата вернуть 1, 0 либо -1